Does the Borsuk-Ulam theorem extend to non-antipodal points?
Is the following generalization of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem true?

For any continuous map $f: S^2 \rightarrow {\mathbb R}^2$ and $d \in {\mathbb R}$ with $0 < d \leq 2$, there exist points $x, y \in S^2$ a distance $d$ apart such that $f(x) = f(y)$.

This becomes the Borsuk-Ulam theorem when $d=2$, the diameter of the unit sphere, because then $x$ and $y$ are antipodal. I suspect it is false, but I couldn't think of a counterexample. For example, its true for the orthographic projection of $S^2$ down onto the plane because points $d$ away from each other on opposite sides of the equator get mapped to the same point. I haven't had success finding an answer online.
This came about when I was talking with someone about the corollary of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem that there are always two antipodal points on Earth with the same temperature and pressure (assuming the Earth is a sphere and temperature and pressure vary continuously). When pressed, I realized I couldn't explain what makes antipodal points special other than that it makes the proof work (I was looking at the proof in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, pg. 33). But it's not clear to me a priori that this generalization couldn't be true by some modified argument. So the question becomes are there always points on Earth a distance $d$ from each other that have the same temperature and pressure?

There will definitely be a more stringent lower bound on $d$ than strictly greater than $0$. Imagine a self-mapping of the sphere taking the form $(1,\theta,\phi) \mapsto (1,(1+k\phi)\theta,\phi)$, in spherical coordinates, which you then project orthogonally onto the plane. Basically, the map rotates and twists the circular horizontal cross sections of the sphere, forming a spiral action, before projecting vertically. As such, only points on similarly sized cross sections can map to the same point. Such circles are too far apart at the poles, and twist to much at the equator, for small $d$s.

@TheoBendit I'm not sure whether that's a well-defined map. It seems to take $(1, 0, \phi)$ and $(1, 2\pi, \phi)$ to different values. If it was defined for just angles between 0 and $2\pi$ to avoid this, it wouldn't be continuous because it would have to "jump" near $\theta = 2\pi$.

Fwiw this exact question has been asked before here, which has an accepted answer that's wrong but can't be deleted by the answerer for being accepted. Perhaps it's at least possible to learn from that some part of what won't work...

@Mathyland Yes, good point. I think a spiral map like this should be possible though, with a different formula.

Yes, such a generalization holds. Moreover, it was proven by Hopf in
Hopf, Heinz, Eine Verallgemeinerung bekannter Abbildungs- und Überdeckungssätze, Port. Math. 4, 129-139 (1944). ZBL0060.40612.
that for every continuous map $f: S^n\to \mathbb R^n$ and every $\alpha\in [0,\pi]$ there exists a pair of points $x, y\in S^n$ at the angular distance $\alpha$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. Hopf's paper is hard to access, but the result is a consequence of the main theorem in
Liu, Yuhong, On a property of functions on the sphere and its application, Nonlinear Anal., Theory Methods Appl., Ser. A, Theory Methods 73, No. 10, 3376-3381 (2010). ZBL1202.55001.
which is accessible. It might be a good student project to write a modern proof of Hopf's result.

Actually, as Borsuk-Ulam is a topological theorem, it has nothing to do (to my understanding) with vector space properties such as "the opposite of". At least that seems clear when reading the proof by Tucker's lemma (and considering that Tucker's lemma itself is usually presented with too narrow hypotheses). So it should stay true when composing $S^n$ with any self-homeomorphism, shouldn't it? Which includes plenty of generalizations such as the OP's and Hopf's.

@Jean-ArmandMoroni: I do not understand your comment. In any case, if you have a new question, you know how to ask (by writing a new post).
